# Scroll View not functioning IOS 7

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, ios7

I have a scrollview inside which i have 20 UItextviews. The scrollview is not working. I have set the following in viewdidload.

```
self.MainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1800);
```

Still it doesn't scroll.  However, if i give bounce vertically, it just bounces. My scrollview is a child of the main UIview of dimension 320*600. Please guide how to enable the scroll!!

[image]

Comment: What's the frame of your ``UISCrollView``?

Comment: have you add scrollview from storyboard?

Comment: MainScroll, please find the screenshot of my settings!!

Comment: I would bet that MainScroll isn't tied to the actual scrollview you are seeing on your screen.

Comment: Tied it correctly mate, just rechecked!!

Comment: @bharath At that point I would the try to do something else to MainView. Set the view to bounce from code, not IB and see if it works.  Make sure self.MainView is not nil etc..

Comment: please check autoresizing mask of scrollview and it should be UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight and check automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets ,its should set no.as well set scrollview height as view height.

Comment: How to set the autoresizing factor? and automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There are two ways you can get the scrolling to work.

**Approach 1 (with code):**

1) Pin `UIScrollView` to the sides of its parent view, as mentioned below.

[image]

2) Set content size of your scroll view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.MainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1800);
}
```

**Approach 2 (pure IB, no code required):**

1) Setting `contentSize` is not required if using `AutoLayout`. You need to pin your `UIScrollView` to the parent view as mentioned below:

[image]

2) Then add another `UIView` inside UIScrollView to act as a content view and pin it to the UIScrollView and move all controls inside this content view:

[image]

3) Pin content view to its parent scroll view as mentioned below:

[image]

4) Set your UIViewController's Simulated Metrics to Freeform (this is important):

[image]

5) Size your content `UIView` to your desired height (obviously important too):

[image]

> Apple article explaining UIScrollView and AutoLayouts:
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: No mate, not working, can anyone share a link or a proj where you have accomplished the same so that it would be a great reference!!

Comment: I have modified my answer with step by step instructions, please let me know if it still does not works!

Comment: Finally! Thank you Yas! Your excellent post put an end to my three day quest to understand the Apple document about scrollviews and autolayout ;)

Comment: Yas: As you mentioned I can not add new constraints as they are disabled when I try to pin UIScrollView.

Comment: Alright got it working. It was because my Scrollview was not a subview of UIView. I directly added UIScrollView to UIViewController.

Comment: +1 for you after 3 hours of frustrating attempts got it worked.

Comment: implementing viewDidLayoutSubviews was the key. contentSize set in viewDidLoad was ignored, thanks (I got this working without autolayout)

Comment: +1 for viewDidLayoutSubviews.... For static layouts (nibs) that code can even go in viewDidLoad. For dynamically-built layouts I had it in viewWillAppear, which is fine in iOS8, but not in iOS7. viewDidLayoutSubviews is perfect for both. Cheers

Comment: The key bit I was missing was not pinning the subviews inside the scrollview to *all* sides. Until I did that the scrollview didn't know how big the content was and thus didn't scroll.

Comment: Thanks for too much explanation

Answer (score -1):

Update the content size after some delay as below.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateContentSize)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:0.25];

}

-(void)updateContentSize{
    UIView *viewLast = [viewContent viewWithTag:100];
    scrollViewAd.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, CGRectGetMaxY(viewLast.frame));
}
```

Comment: Where is the explanation why this solves the problem?