# Scrolling a small amount with AutoLayout or Not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, viewcontroller

I have read a ton of articles on this and I'm just not sure on the way to go. I have a view controller which contains a few text fields and a datePicker. The interface was built for the 4" iPhone screens but now to support the 4s, I'm noticing that of course the UI is cut off. This brings me to my task of wanting to implement a scrolling feature within the ViewController so when the keyboard is up, the user can scroll (just like in Contacts.app for both size phones.

By default the app is using AutoLayouts, but I know with this, you don't use contentSize to set the scrollview size.

With having not really dealt with AutoLayout (apart from my intensive reading today relating to UIScrollViews, I'm wondering what's the best way to go here.

Should I disable Autolayout and go with the content size.

If so, I have the following hierarchy:

- View

  - Scroll View

    - Contents

It started off being View and Contents below it, but I added in the ScrollView and then added the Contents to the Scroll View as above. It of course messed things up so I had to realign everything to its place.

If Autolayout is the way to go with this, could someone point me to some tricks to achieve this scrolling effect? I've read so many articles that I know it's not impossible, I just cannot get my head around it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this one, it explains how can you achieve scrolling with auto layout and without it.

Note: To avoid messing up control positions when adding `UIScrollView`, please look at the step 2.

[Scroll View not functioning IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502860/scroll-view-not-functioning-ios-7/20503513#20503513)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response and your answer on the other question is brilliant with the annotations. Unfortunately I tried step 1 first but there was no scrolling and with step 2, at the very last point, setting the view size.. it really messes up the UI but its still not scrollable unfortunately.. I will revert back to just before trying this and try step 2 again

Comment: I think I'm almost there - the view is certainly scrolling, but it's removed the background image (I'm sure I can put that back) and I'm getting 3 warnings (Ambigious Layout - 2 views are horizontally ambigious) but I feel I'm almost there! Still going to try working on it

Comment: You can set your `UIScrollView`s background color to clear color via IB/Xcode to bring back the background. The views that are horizontally ambiguous, you need to add height constraint to them or pin their top and bottom to the parent controls.

Comment: When adding the new constraints - in your answer, everything is set to 0.. should that be the case? I'm just unfortunately not getting anywhere with this.. do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Well that is for the parent view, not the child. Can you share a screenshot and indicate which view has the warning?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this - really appreciate it. I've got it working to a stage that I really like - It's scrolling nicely - it's just the warnings are confusing me.. so http://d.pr/i/RN6G and http://d.pr/i/sNOi - the three warnings are now solely the ambitious warnings - one is the height for the "Content" View and the other is the width! - thanks so much Yas

Comment: No worries man, glad I could help. Re layouts, select "Content" view and hit that [+] button at the bottom-right and check the "Width" checkbox. It should remove both scroll view and content width warnings. Pls let me know if it does not work.

Comment: That word! and as you said, that gets rid of all the warnings. Wow. Thank you so much man - really - this was one of the last stumbling blocks before my app has finished and this is a big headache sorted - again - thanks so much! if I could vote it up twice, I would!

Comment: Super cool, thanks man. Scroll views are easy but very confusing and poorly documented by Apple. Regardless, you got them to work :)

Comment: Thanks man - you'd think Apple would take the effort to document it better - but thanks again! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43180/discussion-between-lavanya-and-yas-kuraishi)