# iOS ScrollView scroll size to small

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to learn how to use Autolayout with UIScrollView's. I've found a document which explains a single case pretty wel, which is found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

Now I expanded this example to load multiple images and now I find that the scroll size is not automatically resized? It only happens for the first. Am I doing something wrong or is this just the way it is? Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [scroll setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"widget" : scroll};
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[widget]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[widget]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];

    UIImageView *last = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"afl.jpg"]];
        [imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [scroll addSubview:imageView];

        if(last){
            views = @{@"image" : imageView, @"last" : last};

            [scroll addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[image]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];
            [scroll addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[last]-[image]" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];
        }else{
            views = @{@"image" : imageView};

            [scroll addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[image]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];
            [scroll addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[image]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];
        }

        last = imageView;

    }
}
```

With this example I can see the next image beginning when I have  bounces on but the scroll size prohibit me to scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got just... I've been searching for long time (before posting this question. So instead of deleting this question. I will answer it. The reason why you do not have to set the content size is because it automatically sets it to fit to whatever you put in it the first object. The next image will be displayed below it but the scrollview won't reset its content size. So you will have to update the constraint. The way I did this is with only two images (to not make the problem be any harder than it is) is below in my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [scroll setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"widget" : scroll};
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[widget]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[widget]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];

    UIImageView *last = nil;

    NSArray *hConstraint = nil;
    NSArray *vConstraint = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"afl.jpg"]];
        [imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [scroll addSubview:imageView];

        if(last){
            views = @{@"image" : imageView, @"last" : last};

            [scroll addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[image]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];

            vConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[last]-[image]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views];
            [scroll updateConstraints];
        }else{
            views = @{@"image" : imageView};

            hConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[image]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views];
            vConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[image]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views];
            [scroll addConstraints:hConstraint];
            [scroll addConstraints:vConstraint];
        }

        last = imageView;

    }
}
```

So basically I updated the height constraint which is bound to the content size

Answer (score 0):

This post explains using `AutoLayout` with `UIScrollView` in a bit more detail with step by steps instructions.

[Scroll View not functioning IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502860/scroll-view-not-functioning-ios-7/20503513#20503513)