# Arranging bottom toolbar issues iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I apologize in advance for the unusual stack question here, but I'm having some terrible difficulty(refer the image below)

[image: Issue]

I'm trying to set a `UIToolbar` or `UIView` or maybe even a `UITableViewCell` at the bottom of this view where I can set my create button but when I attempt to do so, they all align to the top to fit underneath the cell above (the one containing the `UITextView`).

Aside from this, I need the `UIButton` (*no matter what it lies in*) to remain at the bottom of the view, regardless of screen size.
In other words, the "create" button needs to stay at the bottom of the view for 3.5-inch retina **and** 4-inch retina.

Currently I have placed down a `UIView`, expanded it to the bottom of the `UITableViewController`, layer a toolbar at the bottom of the view and then placed the `UIButton` in the toolbar.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: can you add a screenshot of how it looks on your device running?

Comment: so why don't you simply resize the `UITableView` frame to be 30px shorter than `self.view`? Then take a `UIButton` (_height of 30px_) and pin it to the bottom of the screen (_again... `self.view` **not** `tableView.view`_). Right now, it seems that you are trying to put this in the `tableView`'s view so technically, it will scroll with the rest of the `tableView` (which is not what you want... right?)

Comment: That's a much simpler idea, and I'm trying that right now, the problem is that I have a table view inside a tableviewcontroller, and I can't seem to even edit the table view(can't change the size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a container view such as `UIToolbar` or `UIView`, you can do this with just a `UIButton`. However, if you are intending to add more than one buttons, then `UIToolbar` is probably gonna be a better choice.

Anyways, to pin a control to the bottom of your screen regardless of size, you need to set its vertical spacing to the `Bottom Layout Guide` in your storyboard.

Please make sure your `UIButton` is on the top of `UITableView` not below. To ensure that, make sure `UIButton` is listed below `UITableView` in the Interface Builder's document tree.

Here is a screenshot of how your `UIButton` constraints and position in the document tree may look like!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is an awesome answer @Yas Kuraishi, right now I'm trying to follow all of your steps. Ill vote as answer once I've got it worked out.

Comment: Honestly I can't figure out how to add constraints in Xcode 5

Comment: This post should show you how to pin a view's left, right, top, and bottom to its parent. You only need to pin, your button's left and right and check height checkbox, then control+drag your button to bottom layout guide, and then select vertical from the popup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502860/scroll-view-not-functioning-ios-7/20503513#20503513

Comment: I actually just learned that I'm having problems setting constraints because I'm using a UITableViewController, but thanks for all your input on this man, I'm gunna use it while setting up the new VC @Yas Kuraishi